# Codeigniter 3 create dynamic methods

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working in a app where I need to create database tables on the fly, I did that. But now I need an elegant way to access the database tables. So here is my problem

In regular practice we create a database table and create a class to map a table (ORM). But I cannot take that approach in this case. THis is what I have done so far..

I am extending the MY_Model in the Crud Model, I try to setup the database table name in the set_table() method. It works fine.

```
class Crud extends MY_Model
{

    private $customer_id;

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_database = $this->load->database('customer', TRUE);
    }


    public function set_table($customer_id, $table_name)
    {
        $this->customer_id = $customer_id;
        $this->_table = 'tbl_' . $customer_id . '_' . $table_name;
    }
}
```

Test.php Controller to test the code.

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index(){

        $this->load->model('editor/crud');

        var_dump($this->crud->set_table(1, 'alpha'));
        var_dump($this->crud->get_all());
    }
}
```

But I need an elegant way to access the table. eg.

```
$this->alpha->get_all()
```

OR

`$this->crud->alpha->get_all()`

would be easy to understand & it will make much sense. Is it actually possible to do in PHP? Any help would be much appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you can do something like:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index(){

        $this->load->model('editor/crud');
        $this->crud->set_table(1, 'alpha');

        $this->alpha = clone $this->crud; // in case you use set_table again

        $info = this->alpha->get_all();

    }
}
```

If I recall correctly, you should be able to do it in the model too.

```
public function set_table($customer_id, $table_name)
{

    $this->customer_id = $customer_id;
    $this->_table = 'tbl_' . $customer_id . '_' . $table_name;
    $this->{$table_name} = clone $this;
}
```

and then access it like: `$this->crud->alpha->get_all()`;

Comment: Is it possible to do the altering in the model? I need it be encapsulated in the model.